# I am trying to add add Search filter in react but I am getting this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

1. I am trying to add Seach filter using the react, and using json data
   I am trying to match it with the search term
2. Below is my code

   const App = () => {
   const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState([""])
   const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

   useEffect(() => {
   const url = "https://60d075407de0b20017108b89.mockapi.io/api/v1/animals";

   ```
   const fetchData = async () =>
     {
             try
         {
             const response = await fetch(url);
             const json = await response.json();
             console.log([json].query);
             setQuery(json.query);
         }
             catch (error)
         {
             console.log("error", error);
         }
     };
     fetchData();
   ```

   }, []);

   return (

   <input type='text' placeholder='search....' onChange={event => { setSearchTerm(event.target.value) }} />

   ```
     {

             query.filter((val) => {
               if (searchTerm === "s")
         {
             return val
         }
             else if (val.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
             return val
         }
         else
             return false
         }).map((val) =>
         {
             return (
             <div className='user' >
             <p>{val.name}</p>
             <p>age: {monthDiff(val.bornAt)} months</p>

           </div>
         );
         })}
   </div>
   ```

   );
   };

**When I try to execute, I am getting this below error
can anyone explain why it is happening**

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'toLowerCase')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you able to fix the formatting if your code? I think you have a few ` s out of place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're initializing `query` to a string instead of an array of strings.

Maybe try changing this:

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
```

to

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState([""]);
```

Also, your `searchTerm` **is** initialized to an array: you might have just mixed those up :)

Comment: Yes, thank you for identifying this issue. There is no error now!!

Comment: You're welcome! If this helped you can mark the answer as accepted :)